# How to introduce foster kittens to resident cat that doesn't seem bothered by them?

Tags: cats, introducing-pets, fostering

so I am fostering three 6 week kittens and have a resident two year old cat. The kittens have been introduced to her with them in their carrier and she really doesn't seem bothered by them. She had a sniff then carried on  but they hiss at her. My cat is used to dogs (we are currently fostering a dog too that isn't in the house at present) and she has met other cats when my friends brought theirs over. She is probably more comfortable with dogs to be honest because she has plenty of high places to escape to. When do you think it is safe to let them out and meet her?

**EDIT:** My resident cat has since started to growl at the kittens in the carrier after one of the kittens hissed at her so I assume I should continue the introduction in the traditional way of separate secure rooms and slow supervised introductions.

Comment: You pretty much have it handled, it's perfectly normal for the cats to be like this - when we fostered two very young kittens, our cat wasn't too fond of them however she was mainly idle, despite having hissed or hit one of them in the head once. Anyway, good luck, I really support the idea of supervised introduction, as it worked for us.

Comment: Thanks D. Tanya, it won't be for a very long time until they are left unsupervised for sure, they are just too tiny! When I asked my initial question I thought they were instantly going to be friendly to each other but as my edit suggests some time to get familiar is definitely necessary.

Comment: Yep! Cats by nature are strict on their territories so the cats will need some time (normally it doesn't take longer than a week) to figure out their boundaries. If I am lucky enough to get on a computer, I will link a short 'documentary' video on introducing cats that I've seen earlier and found myself completely enticed by the commentary.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_mgXHAMDZI This has more parts to it, by the way.

Comment: Thanks @D. Tanya these were a great little series to watch!